# Multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue when a symmetric matrix has $m$ identical rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix of order $n$.
>   Show that if $A$ has $m$ identical rows then $A$ has a zero eigenvalue of multiplicity at least $m-1$.

**My try**:

Since $A$ has $m$ identical rows by elementary row operations we have $m-1$ rows of $A$  equal to $0$.

Hence $A$ has geometric multiplicity of $0$ to be equal to atleast $m-1$.
Since $A$ is symmetric so the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ equals its geometric multiplicity and so it is atleast $m-1$.

But how to show that it is equal to exactly $m-1$?

Will you please help?

Comment: I've edited the problem statement, because the original one is false (counterexample: $A=\pmatrix{1&1&0\\ 1&1&0\\ 0&0&0}$ has $m=2$ identical rows but the multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is $m$).

Comment: @user1551; thanks but will u say what to assume so that the problem is true

Comment: @user1551;i guess here the problem is itself wrong